# Possible to Install Lubuntu 12.04 over an existing dual boot Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: 12.04, installation, dual-boot, lubuntu, reinstalling

I recently installed Ubuntu 13.04 on an AMD 64-bit HP Slimline machine(1 GB of RAM expanded to 2GB) that is about 5-7 years old, and I believe/realized that it would probably work/perform better if I installed 12.04 LTS instead. Is it possible to downgrade from vanilla Ubuntu 13.04 to Lubuntu 12.04, or just to simply re-install over it?

P.S. I am dual booting Ubuntu and Windows 7, and have a 20 GB ext4 partition in which my Ubuntu raring installation resides on. (200 GB total disk space)

Thanks in advance.
(I don't post to forums to often so feel free to correct me if I did anything wrong!:-))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not shure is there a downgrade option, but I'd recommend that you reinstall Lubuntu.

When you start installation of Lubuntu/Ubuntu, and you get to the "Instalation type" part choose option "Something else". There will be partition with Ubuntu on it (the one with ext4 format), just delete that partition and add new one on your free space. When you create new partition set the Mount point to "/". And that will format Ubuntu and install Lubuntu on same disc space. If you need to back-up files you can always copy them into Windows disc and get it back once you install Lubuntu.

I hope this is helpfull, here is a link to a simular video if you get lost:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ba9Wv-XU_4M

Comment: ok nver mind I got it sorted out(i ended up not downgrading)
but still I appreciate the help!